# Alternate between Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

my first question here since I can't find anything anywhere and I'm wondering if it can't be done at all.

I have an ASP.NET WebForms Application that uses Role Authentication.
Right now each user has a single role with specific Access Rules. What I'm trying to do is to implement multiple roles for each user with different Access Rules and via a dropdown menu allow the user to select which role will be used, and consequently use the Access Rules specified for that particular role.

So is it at all possible to alternate and let the user choose which role will be active each time?

Comment: As a UX consideration: why require the user to toggle their role, instead of checking their combined authorization?

Comment: Thank you for replying Flater. That was my initial thought but the specifications "prefer" the alternation. If it can't be done at all then combined authorization is the best case scenario..